# Yii2 remove index from canonical

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

Because the default action in Yii2 is `index`, Yii2 redirects `http://example.com/sample` to `SampleController->actionIndex()`.

Now when I generate the canonical it generates `http://example.com/sample/index` as the canonical. What I want is `http://example.com/sample`, so without the `/index` because that is already obvious and I don't want any visitors (or bots) to see that it's actually going to `/index`.

I tried to add this rule `'<controller>/<action:index>' => '<controller>'` to the `rules` section of the `urlManager` (frontend/config/main.php).

Also found [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/342/how-to-hide-index-action-from-url/) for Yii1.1. But it should be easier with Yii2 right?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you and have a great day.
Melle Dijkstra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it working now with the following rule:

`'<controller>' => '<controller>/index'`

Hope this helps anyone having the same situation.